# How to get Google Earth Engine `DateSlider` to have a period of one calendar month?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have a dataset that stores bands by calendar months and I want to make a dateslider so the user can scrub through them. The [`ui.DateSlider`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ui-dateslider) looks like almost what I want, but I have to choose a static number of days over the range rather than calendar months. Is there a way to build a dateslider in the Google Earth Engine UI so that it scrubs through months rather than days? Something like this:

```
      var dateSlider = ui.DateSlider({
        start: start_date,
        end: end_date,
        value: end_date,
        period: 'month',
        }
      });
```

Comment: You can try by setting the `period` value to 30, the slider will start showing monthly intervals. The period value needs to be an integer greater than 0.